# polynomial has solution modulo prime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)$.

For every prime $p$ show that $f(x)\equiv 0 \mod p$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$

I do not know how to start...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For primes $2,3$, such $x$ must exist.

For all primes that are not $2$ or $3$, note that $(\frac{a}{p})\times (\frac{b}{p})=(\frac{ab}{p})$ where $(\frac{a}{p})$ is the [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Thus, note that $(\frac{2}{p})\times (\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{6}{p})$.

This implies if $(\frac{2}{p})$ is $-1$ and $(\frac{3}{p})$ is $-1$, then $(\frac{6}{p})$ is $1$ following from the equation above.

This statement is equivalent to saying that if $2,3$ both are a quadratic non-residue of $p$, then $6$ is a quadratic residue.

**HINT $2$**

Without quadratic residues, note that if there exists such $x$ that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$, this implies that $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. This follows from primitive roots and Fermat's Little Theorem.  This is also known as [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: Yes for primes $2$ and $3$ it is clear.. $x=2$ and $x=3$ are solutions respectively

Comment: I am bit confused about both the hints... Are you saying for each prime $p$, if $p$ does not divide $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$ then $p$ divides $x^2-6$?

Comment: No: If there exists  no $x$ that $x^2-2$ can be divided by $p$ and there exists no $x$ that $x^2-3$ that can be divided by $p$, then there exists such $x$ that $x^2-6$ can be divided by $p$.

Comment: Ok... This makes some sense now.. what i have said previously was non sense... So, Suppose $x^2\neq 2 \mod p$ and $x^2\neq 3$ mod $p$ then we have $2^{p-1}=-1\mod p$ and $3^{p-1}=-1\mod p$ so, taking product, we get $6^{p-1}=1\mod p$ so, $x^2\equiv 6\mod p$ fir some $p$

Comment: @cello Yep, that seems about right.

Comment: @cello This can actually be generalized for all $n$, but not in this case.

Comment: @cello It should be $2^{(p-1)/2}$ and $3^{(p-1)/2}$

Comment: @Farnight I think that is a mistake since someone solving this should be aware of Fermat's Little Theorem. But you are right, of course. I did miss that on cello's comment.

Comment: @Farnight : Yes Yes... I got iy